# Why std::thread accepts a functor by forwarding reference

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, forwarding-reference

Why does a `std::thread` object accept the function parameter by forwarding reference and then make a copy of the object with `decay_copy`?  Wouldn't it be easier to just accept the function object by value?

In general why would one not template a function so as to take a function object by value?  Can reference-ness not be imitated with `reference_wrapper`s (which would be more explicit, and also conveniently has a member `operator()` to call the stored function)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does a `std::thread` object accept the function parameter by forwarding reference and then make a copy of the object with decay_copy? Wouldn't it be easier to just accept the function object by value?

It has to have a copy of the function object in a storage that it can guarantee lasts as long as the thread it is about to launch lasts.

A function argument to construct `std::thread` would not last that long, as the line where `std::thread` is created can end long before the created thread ends.

So it must make a copy.  If it took its argument by-value, it would make a copy when the constructor was called, then have to make *another* copy to the persistent storage.  By taking it by forwarding reference, it makes *exactly one* copy.

Now this additional copy could be moved-to, making the extra overhead one extra move.  This is still extra overhead, as not all constructs are cheap to move.

> In general why would one not template a function so as to take a function object by value?

Because that mandates an extra `move`.

> Can reference-ness not be imitated with reference_wrappers (which would be more explicit, and also conveniently has a member operator() to call the stored function)?

In the case where you intend to store the function object, taking by forwarding reference saves a move, and doesn't require much extra work on the part of the writer of the function-object taking code.

If the caller passed in a reference wrapper, the value stored would be the reference wrapper, which has a different meaning.

Comment: I honestly didn't think the answer would be so simple.. it's so easy to overcomplicate things sometimes